# For loop to take mean of object properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, mapbox

I have an array of features that I would like to find the average of by a property

```
var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['my_layer']});
console.log(features)
```

This returns:

```
(10) [Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature, Feature]
0:Feature
layer:{id: "my_layer", type: "circle", source: "tbr", filter: Array(3), layout: {…}, …}
properties:{bikeid: 15847, diff.time: 2.25, …}
```

However, when I try to take the sum and length of each feature's `diff.time` property, a syntax error is returned with an unexpected identifier.

```
var sum = 0 
var length = 0    

    for each (var feature in features) {
    sum += feature.properties['diff.time'];
    length ++

    }

    console.log(sum/length)


Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How is this syntax incorrect and what should be changed to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Hint: what is `for each`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 3 issues with your code.

`for each` is not a valid loop in javascript, `Array#forEach` is a method on an array however.

When you do a `for in` you should be iterating over an objects keys, it will still work but you will loop over the length property and will not be as efficient at iterating over an array, so in this case you should do a `for` loop and iterate over your array's index.

The last issue is that naming a property `diff.time` while it's legal is not a good way to name a property as you will not be able to access it with the dot operator.

```
var sum = 0
var length = 0

for(var i; i < features.length; i+=1) {
  sum += features[i].properties['diff.time']; // don't think diff.time will work
  length++
}

console.log(sum / length)
```

That aside javascript has a better more explicit way to do it using `Array#reduce` to change an array of values into a single value.

```js
class Feature {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
    this.properties = {
      'diff.time': 2.25 // this is a not a good way to name a property
    }
  }
}

const features = [
  new Feature(1),
  new Feature(2),
  new Feature(3),
]

console.log(
  features.reduce((acc, x) => {
    return acc + x.properties['diff.time']
  }, 0)
)
```